# TensorFlow C++ api. Is there a way to change a vector to a matrix without copying?

Tags: c++, tensorflow2.0

Is there a better way to change a vector to a matrix by changing the shape only or using the same memory?

Here is the code for changing a vector to a matrix by copying what I'm currently using.

```
  //Change the vector to a matrix
  auto n{y.tensor().tensor<float,1>().size()};
  Tensor y_matrix(DT_FLOAT, {1, n});
  assert( y_matrix.CopyFrom(y.tensor(), TensorShape({n})));
```

Thanks
PMcG

Comment: Looked at the Tensor documentation and seems as though this shares the underlying storage already.